# Maven Sonarqube Plugin: Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, maven, parallel-processing, sonarqube

Since maven supports multithread builds, would it be possible to also run sonar multithreaded?  (e.g. `mvn sonar:sonar -T 4` )

I ran it and while the module reported success, it reports back as the overall build failing with `java.util.concurrent.ExcutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

As of 6/12/15 it's been resolved that the Maven Sonar plugin does not support Maven 3's parallel build feature: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MSONAR-7